# How can an object property be aware of it's parent item?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, object-oriented-analysis

Assuming the scheme:

```
class ComplexProperty
{
    string PropertyName {get; set;}
    string Description {get; set;}
    string GetParentName(); // How can this be implemented?
}

class Parent
{
    string ParentName {get; set;}
    ComplexProperty Property {get; set;}
}
```

The problem is to get the ParentName from inside the `ComplexProperty`.

The best solution I have come up with is using the constructor of Parent to initialize the property, but this is prone to bugs and fails when you set the property from a different place.

For example:

```
class Parent
{
    public Parent()
    {
       ComplexProperty = new ComplexProperty(this); // Store an instance of the parent inside the property
    }
    string ParentName {get; set;}
    ComplexProperty Property {get; set;}
}
```

Any ideas about this? Is there any best practice for this sort of architecture? Note that the `ComplexProperty` will always be the child of specific interface implementations, so reflection is a viable but not desired solution.

Comment: Does it have to have a public setter?

Comment: Can you please explain what you meant by "prone to bugs and fails when you set the property from a different place" ? YOu could look at modifying the ComplexProperty to have a another property called ParentName or probably have a method called SetParentName which would set a local private variable. Now in the 'ComplexProperty Property {get; set; }' you could modify the setter to change this.

Comment: The `ComplexProperty` has to gather some info and calculate, based on it's context (essentially the item that holds it). For example it needs to get the name of the string property, not the name of the class, so it needs access to the instance of sorts.

Comment: The setter of `ComplexProperty` inside parent can't be forced to remain private. It should be able to change, as the property could be null or it could actually need to change.  It's prone to bugs since if you do something like `new Parent(){ Property = new ComplexProperty()}` it won't work.

Comment: Adding properties to the `ComplexProperty` sure isn't a solution I like, mainly because you repeat data and also because they do not belong inside there. It's the context, I am just not sure how to enable the object to see it's context

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to keep a `Parent` property and set it in the `ComplexProperty` setter.

```
class ComplexProperty
{
    public string PropertyName {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public IParent Parent {get; set;}
    public string GetParentName() 
    {
        return this.Parent == null ? null : this.Parent.Name;
    }
}

interface IParent
{
    string Name {get; set;}
}
class Parent : IParent
{
   public string ParentName {get; set;}

   private ComplexProperty _prop;
   public ComplexProperty Property 
   {
      get { return _prop; }
      set 
      {
          _prop = value;
          _prop.Parent = this; 
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, more boilerplate for the setter but +1 because this actually removes the problem of changing the `ComplexProperty`. It's still the same as my solution which I dont quite like, I don't know why really, seems wrong for some reason

Comment: Actually I just noticed you say ComplexProperty will always be a child of a certain interface so the Parent property should be of that interface type. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a func

```
class ComplexProperty
{   
    private readonly Func<string> GetParentNameFunc;

    string PropertyName {get; set;}
    string Description {get; set;}
    string GetParentName {get {return GetParentNameFunc(); } }

    public ComplexProperty(Func<string> GetParentNameFunc)
    {
      this.GetParentNameFunc = GetParentNameFunc;
    }
}

class Parent
{
    string Name {get; set;}
    ComplexProperty Property {get; set;}

    //...
    //...

    SomeMethodOrCtor()
    {
      Property = new ComplexProperty(()=>{ return this.Name; });
    }

}
```

Comment: How is this better from storing the whole instance reference, other than more code?

Comment: The logic for getting the parent name remains in the parent class, meaning you could add ComplexProperties to any class without having to have that class be of a certain type of implement a certain interface.

Comment: Oh I see, this is not actually a requirement as all the parent classes will be of certain interfaces, and this strong coupling of properties would mean a great lot of maintenance in case the context (or the complexproperty) changes! Thank you for the answer

Comment: In that case I'd use a reference to your interface instead of the func, keeping the same pattern (pass it in in the ComplexProperty ctor and store as private readonly)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the EntityFramework, which is basicly made to handle this kind of relationship. However, it comes with an overhead I don't really appreciate. Just look at how many question about this framework ends up here...

Or you could also code your own. In one of the modeling editor I made, I ended up with a Component/Entity setup where the component would need to know it's parent to know the position in space. And the component may also need to know the scene containing the entity.

Using constructor is one way, but may not apply to everything as you may not know the identity of the parent yet.

You can also use accessor, when you change a property, you call something like "SetParent" in the object you recieve.

Also, in the serialization, I ended up doing a rebuild parenting setup because serializing the hierarchy was overkill. Called from the top, I would set the parent in every object contained, then call the same in all child and so on.

Of course, you have to assume an object only have 1 parent. If your whole code is built that way from the start, is not very hard to manage.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This doesn't have to do much with ORM, but I'm using nHibernate anyway. The overhead in my case would be an object factory that would be the only thing to produce Parent classes, and in that case my solution would work all the time because of the fact that ComplexProperty would have a reference to the parent object (much like with relationship mapping in EF)!